# locate exact word in excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have more than one text with the word "123" inside Textabc

like a123b , c123erf and 123

but I just wanna locate the exact word "123"

```
Text_u1 = Mid(Textabc, InStr(Text, "123"))
```

I tried &123& but not working

Thanks

Comment: Still not clear about what you are trying to achieve :(

Answer (score 2):

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetWord()
    Dim Textabc As String, s As Variant, i As Variant, abc As String, sz As Long
    Dim foundStart As Long, foundLen As Long

    Textabc = "like a123b , c123erf and 123"
    abc = "123"

    s = Split(Textabc)

    For i = 0 To UBound(s)

        sz = sz + Len(s(i)) + 1

        If Trim(s(i)) = abc Then

            foundStart = sz - Len(s(i))

            foundLen = Len(Textabc) - (sz - Len(s(i))) + 1

            Debug.Print "Textabc length: " & Len(Textabc)
            Debug.Print "foundStart: " & foundStart
            Debug.Print "foundLen: " & foundLen
            Debug.Print Mid(Textabc, foundStart, foundLen)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these two, depending on what you want:

```
Public Sub TestMe()        
    Debug.Print InStr("a123b", "123")
    Debug.Print Mid("a123b", InStr("a123b", "123"))        
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Regular Expressions

```
Sub Test()
    Dim regEx As Object
    Dim str As String

    Set regEx = CreateObject("vbscript.RegExp")

    str = "a123b , c123erf and 123"

    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "\b(123)"

        Debug.Print regEx.Execute(str)(0).FirstIndex + 1
    End With
End Sub
```

This will return the position of the first match it finds that is equal to just `123` everything else will be ignored. If there are more then one match you will need to loop over the output of `regEx.Execute(str)` to get each position